# I want each HTML line to alternate in color inside a textbox, back and forth

Tags: html, colors, textbox, alternate

I have scrolling HTML text in Actionscript 2.  How do I make each line alternate colors back and forth (for intended readability)?  I don't want to have to code the color for all 600 lines or use mass-replace function, if possible!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Zebra striping](http://csswizardry.com/2010/08/zebra-striping-rows-and-columns/). You don't need to use Javascript for this. The `:nth-child(odd)` in CSS should suffice.

Comment: :nth-child(odd) has zero support in IE8 down, which makes it useless to a good deal of people.